# Parsing a Very Complex JSON file with Jackson Library in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have searched numerous forums, questions, and tutorials to figure out how to parse the below JSON file into a java object. Currently, I have tried full data binding to another class, but I don't want to put all of the keys from the JSON file into that class. Given this issue, I have tried reading in as a tree and going through it that way, but I cannot get that to work either.

Here is an example of the JSON file:

```
{
"tweets": [
    {
        "filter_level": "medium",
        "retweeted_status": {
            "contributors": null,
            "text": "It's winter, right?",
            "geo": null,
            "retweeted": false,
            "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
            "truncated": false,
            "lang": "en",
            "entities": {
                "symbols": [

                ],
                "urls": [

                ],
                "hashtags": [

                ],
                "user_mentions": [

                ]
            },
            "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
            "id": 419133079765016576,
            "source": "<a href=\"http://www.echofon.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">Echofon<\/a>",
            "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
            "favorited": false,
            "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
            "retweet_count": 2,
            "created_at": "Fri Jan 03 15:48:07 +0000 2014",
            "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
            "favorite_count": 0,
            "id_str": "419133079765016576",
            "place": null,
            "user": {
                "location": "",
                "default_profile": false,
                "profile_background_tile": true,
                "statuses_count": 55398,
                "lang": "en",
                "profile_link_color": "E03019",
                "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/32943506/1354602333",
                "id": 32943506,
                "following": null,
                "protected": false,
                "favourites_count": 168,
                "profile_text_color": "F22805",
                "description": "IG: baldhead_jay",
                "verified": false,
                "contributors_enabled": false,
                "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
                "name": "Jazzmen",
                "profile_background_color": "080808",
                "created_at": "Sat Apr 18 17:06:09 +0000 2009",
                "default_profile_image": false,
                "followers_count": 919,
                "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/418581792082239488/qqmW8FDf_normal.jpeg",
                "geo_enabled": false,
                "profile_background_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/712526073/ff1708a70b892c6635a263a66c592216.jpeg",
                "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/712526073/ff1708a70b892c6635a263a66c592216.jpeg",
                "follow_request_sent": null,
                "url": null,
                "utc_offset": -28800,
                "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
                "notifications": null,
                "profile_use_background_image": true,
                "friends_count": 802,
                "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "0A0A09",
                "screen_name": "_PumpsAndJays",
                "id_str": "32943506",
                "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/418581792082239488/qqmW8FDf_normal.jpeg",
                "listed_count": 4,
                "is_translator": false
            },
            "coordinates": null
        },
        "contributors": null,
        "text": "RT @_PumpsAndJays: It's winter, right? I'm going to need yal to shut the hell up about all this snow! ðŸ˜’",
        "geo": null,
        "retweeted": false,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [

            ],
            "urls": [

            ],
            "hashtags": [

            ],
            "user_mentions": [
                {
                    "id": 32943506,
                    "name": "Jazzmen",
                    "indices": [
                        3,
                        17
                    ],
                    "screen_name": "_PumpsAndJays",
                    "id_str": "32943506"
                }
            ]
        },
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "id": 419137024818282496,
        "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android<\/a>",
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "favorited": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Fri Jan 03 16:03:48 +0000 2014",
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "id_str": "419137024818282496",
        "place": null,
        "user": {
            "location": "Chicago",
            "default_profile": false,
            "profile_background_tile": false,
            "statuses_count": 22140,
            "lang": "en",
            "profile_link_color": "1CA5C7",
            "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/88852465/1374562212",
            "id": 88852465,
            "following": null,
            "protected": false,
            "favourites_count": 77,
            "profile_text_color": "030103",
            "description": "A graduate from Central State University. I'm a laid back kind of girl.",
            "verified": false,
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "081012",
            "name": "Renee",
            "profile_background_color": "AB0D28",
            "created_at": "Tue Nov 10 04:40:41 +0000 2009",
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "followers_count": 263,
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000596965744/512ee5834ca9977193deb181d0130d33_normal.jpeg",
            "geo_enabled": true,
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/383615087/paris.jpg",
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/383615087/paris.jpg",
            "follow_request_sent": null,
            "url": null,
            "utc_offset": -21600,
            "time_zone": "Central Time (US & Canada)",
            "notifications": null,
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "friends_count": 390,
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "690966",
            "screen_name": "SuitNTaiShyt",
            "id_str": "88852465",
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000596965744/512ee5834ca9977193deb181d0130d33_normal.jpeg",
            "listed_count": 2,
            "is_translator": false
        },
        "coordinates": null
    },
    {
        "filter_level": "medium",
        "contributors": null,
        "text": "U know your ice fishing at home when ur snacks are sandwiches,chips,dips,beef jerky and all the goodies instead of just a case of beer #mom",
        "geo": null,
        "retweeted": false,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "entities": {
            "symbols": ["id"

            ],
            "urls": [

            ],
            "hashtags": [
                {
                    "text": "mom",
                    "indices": [
                        135,
                        139
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "user_mentions": [

            ]
        },
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "id": 419137025376145408,
        "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone<\/a>",
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "favorited": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "created_at": "Fri Jan 03 16:03:48 +0000 2014",
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "id_str": "419137025376145408",
        "place": null,
        "user": {
            "location": "",
            "default_profile": false,
            "profile_background_tile": true,
            "statuses_count": 5411,
            "lang": "en",
            "profile_link_color": "17EBCF",
            "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/408240224/1384838946",
            "id": 408240224,
            "following": null,
            "protected": false,
            "favourites_count": 4222,
            "profile_text_color": "333333",
            "description": "It is what it is, no more, no less. Trust in the Lord. BSU Softball #5.  My whole being is happy - Psalm 16:9",
            "verified": false,
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
            "name": "Nicole Anne",
            "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
            "created_at": "Wed Nov 09 05:03:58 +0000 2011",
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "followers_count": 452,
            "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/413270299925164033/mWiJBKP2_normal.jpeg",
            "geo_enabled": true,
            "profile_background_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/698793822/14d9ce538d96b435ad4449d5385a3ec1.jpeg",
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/698793822/14d9ce538d96b435ad4449d5385a3ec1.jpeg",
            "follow_request_sent": null,
            "url": null,
            "utc_offset": -32400,
            "time_zone": "Alaska",
            "notifications": null,
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "friends_count": 634,
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
            "screen_name": "NDupay",
            "id_str": "408240224",
            "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/413270299925164033/mWiJBKP2_normal.jpeg",
            "listed_count": 1,
            "is_translator": false
        },
        "coordinates": null
    },
```

As you can see, it is extremely complicated at first sight; however, I included that much to show you something. This is a sample json file representing tweets from twitter, none of it being real.

Here is my main parsing code:

```
private static File twitterFile;

public TweetJSONParser(File twitterFile) {
    TweetJSONParser.twitterFile = twitterFile;
}

private static String jsonFile() {

    String jsonFile = twitterFile.getName();
    return jsonFile;
}

public Tweet getTweet() {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Tweet tweet = new WeatherTweet();

    try {
        tweet = mapper.readValue(new File(jsonFile()), WeatherTweet.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return tweet;
}
```

And this is the class I have been using:

```
public class Tweet {

private String source;
private Boolean retweeted;
private int retweetCount;
private int contributors;
private Boolean favorited;
private int favoriteCount;
private String id;
private String text;
private String time;
private String location;
private String coordinates;
private String classification = null;

ArrayList<String> userMentions;
ArrayList<String> hashtags;
//ArrayList<String> symbols;

//Constructor
public Tweet() {
    retweeted = false;
    favorited = false;

    hashtags = new ArrayList<String>();
    userMentions = new ArrayList<String>();

}

public String getClassification() {
    return classification;
}

public void setClassification(String classification) {
    this.classification = classification;
}


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setid(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getSource() {
    return source;
}

public void setSource(String source) {
    this.source = source;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getCoordinates() {
    return coordinates;
}

public void setCoordinates(String coordinates) {
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public void setRetweeted(Boolean retweeted) {
    this.retweeted = retweeted;
}   

public Boolean isRetweeted() {
    return retweeted;
}

public int getContributors() {
    return contributors;
}

public void setContributors(int contributors) {
    this.contributors = contributors;
}

public int getRetweetCount() {
    return retweetCount;
}

public void setRetweetCount(int retweetCount) {
    this.retweetCount = retweetCount;
}

public void setFavorited(Boolean favorited) {
    this.favorited = favorited;
}   

public Boolean isFavorited() {
    return favorited;
}

public int getFavoriteCount() {
    return favoriteCount;
}

public void setFavoriteCount(int favoriteCount) {
    this.favoriteCount = favoriteCount;
}

public class Entities {

    public class UserMentions {

        private String user;

        public String getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(String user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

        public void addUserMention(String user) {
            userMentions.add(user);
        }

        public String getUserMention(int index) {
            return userMentions.get(index);
        }

        public Integer getNumUserMentions() {
            return userMentions.size();
        }
    }

    public class hashtags {

        private String hashtag;

        public String getHashtag() {
            return hashtag;
        }

        public void setHashtag(String hashtag) {
            this.hashtag = hashtag;
        }

        public void addHashtag(String hashtag) {
            hashtags.add(hashtag);
        }

        public String getHashtag(Integer index) {
            return hashtags.get(index);
        }

        public Integer getNumHashtags() {
            return hashtags.size();
        }
    }
}

public class User {

    private String user;
    private String location;
    private String timeZone;
    private String id;
    private String description;
    private String createdAt;
    private int statusesCount;
    private int favouritesCount;
    private int followersCount;
    private Boolean geoEnabled;
    private String url;
    private int utcOffset;
    private int friendsCount;

    public String getTimeZone() {
        return timeZone;
    }

    public void setTimeZone(String timeZone) {
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
    }

    public int getFavouritesCount() {
        return favouritesCount;
    }

    public void setFavouritesCount(int favouritesCount) {
        this.favouritesCount = favouritesCount;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getStatusesCount() {
        return statusesCount;
    }

    public void setStatusesCount(int statusesCount) {
        this.statusesCount = statusesCount;
    }

    public int getFollowersCount() {
        return followersCount;
    }

    public void setFollowersCount(int followersCount) {
        this.followersCount = followersCount;
    }

    public Boolean getGeoEnabled() {
        return geoEnabled;
    }

    public void setGeoEnabled(Boolean geoEnabled) {
        this.geoEnabled = geoEnabled;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public int getUtcOffset() {
        return utcOffset;
    }

    public void setUtcOffset(int utcOffset) {
        this.utcOffset = utcOffset;
    }

    public int getFriendsCount() {
        return friendsCount;
    }

    public void setFriendsCount(int friendsCount) {
        this.friendsCount = friendsCount;
    }   
}
```

}

My question is: I only want to put into the tweet java object (POJO) the tweets that are not retweeted, i.e. those that don't have the "retweeted_status" field after the first field "filter_medium", and with what I have it is not working. Can anyone offer specific help with this? I hope this all makes sense, but since I am entirely new to JSON as of two hours ago, and I am boggled as to how to do this.

**EDIT:**

I apologize for the wording, as pointed out in one of the comments. The underlying issue is that I do *not* know how to parse the JSON file I provided. My efforts thus far to parse what I have are not sorting the data correctly into the class, since I don't understand how to use the libraries for JSON parsing to parse this complex file. It's a little too complex for my own knowledge of the subject currently, and I am seeking your help with how to use the Jackson library, or any other library that is suitable, to correctly parse this file into a Java Object (in this case a class).

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON??

Comment: _"I cannot get that to work either"_ -- in what way? Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] to learn how to write good questions. One important requirement is that you explain what isn't working about your approach.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, see my edit above. Also, thank you for further helping me with the proper posting of questions on StackExchange.

Comment: You originally said you didn't know how to restructure the data, now you say you don't know how to parse it.  You need to learn how to describe your problem better.  And to parse JSON, if you're determined to use Jackson, you need to spend a non-trivial amount of time studying up on how to do it.  I doubt that anyone is going to write your code for you.  There are other parsers that are much simpler, and probably overall easier to use, but they don't hand you the data in POJOs, nicely tied up with a ribbon.

Comment: Hint: Go to json.org and spend 5-10 minutes learning the JSON syntax.  That's all the time it takes.

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't want to put all of the keys from the JSON file into that
>   class

In some way or another you're going to have to define the fields you want to extract from your JSON data, if you want to parse it as a JSON data. I suggest you first learn how to parse JSON using the default (built-in) parser in Android. Once you do, you won't think of your example as a "complex json" anymore.